# For $\alpha>0$, $\frac{\log x}{x^\alpha}\rightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: calculus

Courant & John's *Introduction to Calculus and Analysis Volume I*, p. 251.

> Another simple proof may be suggested: For $x>1$ and $\epsilon>0$
> $$\log x=\int^x_1\frac{d\xi}{\xi}<\int^x_1\xi^{\epsilon-1}d\xi=\frac{1}{\epsilon}(x^\epsilon-1);$$
> if we choose $\epsilon$ equal to $\alpha$ and divide both members of this inequality by $x^\alpha$, then it follows that $(\log x)/x^\alpha\rightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$.

$$\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{x^\alpha-1}{x^\alpha}=\frac{1}{\alpha}(1-\frac{1}{x^\alpha})\rightarrow\frac{1}{\alpha}\text{.}$$
How does the conclusion follow from this?

Comment: It doesn't seem to, does it. Maybe what was intended was to choose $\epsilon=\frac\alpha2$ or something.

Comment: Can't we just use L'hopital's rule to prove the statement?

Answer (score 0):

Yep.
Greg Martin has the right idea,
but it can be done a little more simply.

Writing $c$ for $\epsilon$
because lazy,
you have shown that
$\ln(x)
\lt \dfrac1{c}(x^c-1)
$
so that
$\ln(x)
\lt \dfrac1{c}x^c
$.

Letting $c = \frac{a}{2}$,
this becomes
$\ln(x)
\lt \dfrac1{a/2}x^{a/2}
$
so
$\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x^a}
\lt \dfrac1{a/2}\dfrac{x^{a/2}}{x^a}
= \dfrac{2}{ax^{a/2}}
\to 0
$
as
$x \to \infty
$.